# Selecting entire rows from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I don't know if it's possible and i might be asking a stupid question here, if so, forgive me.
I have two tables that are somewhat similar but not entirely.
Table 1 (user_opinions)

```
    | o_id     | user_id | opinion      |is_shared_from| date,isglobal etc
    |:---------|---------|:------------:|:------------:|
    | 1        |       11|     text 1   | 0
    | 2        |       13|     text 2   | 2
    | 3        |        9|     text 3   | 0
```

Table 2 (Buss_opinions)

```
    | bo_id    | o_id   | user_id      | opinion    | date
    |:---------|--------|:------------:|:------------:|
    | 1        |       2|   52         | bus text 1
    | 2        |       3| 41           | bus text 2
```

If i do a standard select and join like this:

```
SELECT * FROM user_opinions uo
JOIN Buss_opinions bo
ON uo.o_id = bo.o_id
```

This will return rows with both table's data joined together.

My question is, what if i wanted to get data from these two tables in seperate rows.
Result should be something like this:

```
| oid      | bo_id   | opinion      | nb: and other rows from both tables
|:---------|---------|:------------:|
| 1        |    NULL |     text 1   | nb:from table 1
| NULL     |        1|    bus text 1| nb:from table 2
| 2        |    NULL |     text 2   |nb:from table 1
```

and so on

It gets both table's data and where there's no common field it puts a NULL value in the field. Is there a type of join for this? or are there other ways of doing this?

Answer (score 4):

One way you could go about it is using a UNION (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html):

```
SELECT oid AS OID, null AS BOID, user_id AS USERID, opinion AS Opinion
FROM table1
UNION
SELECT null AS OID, bo_id AS BOID, user_id AS USERID, opinion AS Opinion
FROM table2
```

Edit: You could even take this a step further and marry it with the CONCAT function:

```
SELECT CONCAT('OID-', oid) AS ID, user_id AS USERID, opinion AS Opinion
FROM table1
UNION
SELECT CONCAT('BOID-', bo_id) AS ID, user_id AS USERID, opinion AS Opinion
FROM table2
```